# How to pull a single row from a database

Tags: android, sqlite

I currently have the code below it works fine up until I actually try to physically call the data queried. Also can someone given an example on how to query a single ID using a WHERE clause. I tried, but that causes an error before I can even try to pull anything back out.

All help appriciated.
Max

```
String questionval;
    String answer1val;
    String answer2val;
    private final String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "QnA";
    private final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "friends";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " (ID INT(3), Questions VARCHAR, Answer1 VARCHAR," +
                " Answer2 VARCHAR, Answer3 VARCHAR," +
                " Answer4 VARCHAR, CorrectAnswer INT(1), Reason VARCHAR);");

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " Values ('1','" +
                "Question?'," +
                "'Answer1'," +
                "'Answer2'," +
                "'Answer3'," +
                "'Answer4'," +
                "'2'," +
                "'Reason');");

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME , null);


                    questionval = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Question"));
                    answer1val = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Answer1"));
                    answer2val = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Answer2"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `moveToFirst()` on the `Cursor` before trying to access your row.

Comment: I added the moveToFirst, but still am unable to run without an error. Is this what you meant.
     c.moveToFirst();
     questionval = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Question"));
     answer1val = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Answer1"));
     answer2val = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Answer2"));

Comment: @Max: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your error.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the advice. I'm very new, but this is what I think it found. bad request for field slot 0, -1 numRows=11, numColumns=8

Comment: @Max: You have `c.getColumnIndex("Question")`, but your table does not have a column named `Question`. It has a column named `Questions`.

Comment: Thank you ! That fixed that issue. Always such simple things! If you don't mind me asking, did you know from the error what the issue was or did you just read through the scripting again?

Comment: @Max: The error indicated you were asking for a bad column. From there, I glanced at the code again and saw the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help and not just pumping out an answer. I actually learn't. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve value as following.

```
Vector temp = null;

// Fetch the values from database
    Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME,
                    null);

// Extract the values
            if (c != null) {

                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {

                        temp = new Vector();
// Title was the field(column) name of the  table
                    temp.addElement(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Title")));

// Description was the field(column) name of the table      
                        temp.addElement(c
                                .getString(c.getColumnIndex("Description")));

                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Surely I don't need a while loop though. If I am only pulling a single value. From this example how would I pull the result out again ?